# Set ID of current row in cellRenderer function which returns an anchor tag in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to design two action buttons in the action column using cellRenderer function which returns two action button edit and delete, I'm using anchor tag to design these button but I also want that the id of each row should be displayed or set in the data-id attribute of anchor tag, So I can access them using ajax and send it to the server for action like edit and delete.
I've successfully designed the buttons and they are also displaying in the action column but I don't know how to set the id of the row in the data-id attribute of the anchors tag.
I'm using PHP to send json data to the client.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'action.php',
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        fetch_all_users: 1
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        const columnDefs = [{
            field: 'action',
            cellRenderer: function actionBtns() {
              return `<a href="#" class="text-success me-2"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="text-danger delete_user_btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>`;
            },
            width: 80,
          },
          {
            field: "id",
            width: 75,
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "leads",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "codice_ateco",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "sottocategoria",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "divisione",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "sezione",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "citta_legale",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "via_legale",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "citta_operativa",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "via_operativa",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "codicefisacle_azienda",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "partita_iva",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "legale_rappresentante",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "codicefiscale_legale_rappresentante",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "citta_legale_rappresentante",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "via_legale_rappresentante",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "luogo_di_nascita_legale_rappresentante",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "data_di_nascita_legale_rappresentante",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "telefono",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "cellulare",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "email",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "pec",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "codice_univoco",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "interni",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "referente_1",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "referente_2",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "dipendenti_totali",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "sorgente",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "tipologia",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },
          {
            field: "id_azienda",
            sortable: true,
            filter: true
          },

        ];
        // specify the data
        var rowData = [];
        response.forEach(element => {
          rowData.push(element);
        });
        
        // let the grid know which columns and what data to use
        const gridOptions = {
          columnDefs: columnDefs,
          rowData: rowData,
          pagination: true,
          paginationPageSize: 10,

        };

        const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#show_all_users');
        new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

      }
    });
```

This is ajax method
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `getRowNodeId`

```
this.state = {
         getRowNodeId: function (data) {
            return data.id;   // pass id
          }
     }
    
    <AgGridReact
        getRowNodeId={this.state.getRowNodeId}
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Cell renderer function has a parameter `ICellRendererParams`. Use that parameter like `function actionBtns(params: any)`.

Now inside the function, you can get the id like `params.data.id`.

```js
const columnDefs = [{
    field: 'id',
    cellRenderer: function actionBtnRenderer(params) {
      const actionButtons = '<a href="#" class="text-success me-2" data-id="' +
        params.data.id + '">' +
        '<i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>' +
        '<a href="#" class="text-danger delete_user_btn" data-id="' +
        params.data.id + '">' +
        '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>';
      return actionButtons;
    },
    width: 80,
  },
  //...
];
```

Please note that if you pass id as field, `field: 'id'` you can access it as `params.value` too.

Documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/

Comment: How to pass id in the anchor links attribute data-id from the foreach loop you can see in my codes? @naveen